# How does WP determine the difference between a post and a page url

Tags: javascript, rewrite-rules

I'm trying to mimic WP routing in a javascript plugin. I've successfully imported the rewrite rules and am applying them to the browser location. But I can't seem to parse the difference between a page and a post when using pretty permalinks.

From what I've read WP matches the requested URL against a regex and then uses that to create a query with parameters that are extracted from the URL. I believe that these are the  pertinent rewrite rules:

Page:

```
(.?.+?)(/[0-9]+)?/?$: "index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]"
```

Post:

```
([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$: "index.php?name=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]"
```

I guess I want to know what happens after this. One URL could match both of these patterns. Does WP save both matches, run the query, and return the results? Or does it stop looping through the rules after the first rewrite match? And if so how does it know whether its looking for a post or a page?

Comment: Have you looked at the `url_to_postid()` function in `/wp-includes/rewrite.php`?

Comment: Could you explain why you wish to do this? We might have a better solution for you.

Comment: Hey. I'm working on a plugin that will convert rewrite rules into query variables for WP REST API. I'm testing it with an angular theme and I couldn't understand why post requests were returning pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a priority in URL parsing, and page related parsing is the lowest priority, or you might say that page is the default parsing applied when nothing else works. In your example wordpress will first try to treat the URL as a post and if no matching post is found it will try to find a page matching the URL.